# ASP.NET MVC changing post method to save userId

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new to ASP.Net MVC, learning it on my own.
I am trying to create a web-app to allow users to send requests online, 
simply I've to Tables in my Database, using IdentityDbContext to generate userTable, and I got another Table 'Fatwa", 
the user sends a request and saves them in Fatwa Table with UserID, to reference which user sends the request.

my problem is I got the POST request using scaffolding, it works fine, but I don't know how to Attach the userID with the Post request,

I did make it a ForeignKey in the database but don't know how to edit my post request to allow it to save the userID with the request.

please help me

thank you

this is the POST request

```
   // POST: api/Fatwas
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostFatwa([FromBody] Fatwa fatwa)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            _context.Fatwa.Add(fatwa);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetFatwa", new { id = fatwa.FatwaID }, fatwa);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if i understand well you need the current user id, create object of user inside the class of Fatwa to make the relation between the user and fatwa then you can get the user from the current context `HttpContext context` inside the context there are `context.User?.Identity.Name` and much more

Comment: I've the  `private readonly AuthenticationContext _context;
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManger;`   all I just wanted to save userID with each request, to allow admin to know who send the request

Comment: @AAaaAA you are using mvc or mvc core ?

Comment: I am using asp.net with angular

Comment: @AAaaAA
from the name that you can get it from the context you can get the id
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
var userId = user.Id;

Comment: yeah i tried, i sent the userId from angular just fine to the Backend, but when It get to the backend, I don't know how to attach it to Fatwa Table, since it's a foreignKey

Comment: Oh now i understand, in Fatwa table there are object for the user u need to get the user by id and pass it to fatwa.user object something like fatwa.user = getuserbyId(1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202968/discussion-between-moath-naji-and-aaaaaa).